# indentation of long lines in algorithm2e and vertical spacing problem

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

After spending 2 hrs on this and trying all sorts of things, I give up. I am using `algorithm2e` and when I have long description lines, the new line gets shifted a little to the right. Also, even though I add new empty line between two paragraphs, no empty line shows up in the output.

First, here is diagram of the problem, with the code that generated it below

[image]

Code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\Input{$y'=f(x,y)$} 
Assume expansion around $x_0$ with initial conditions $y(x_0)=y_0$

\eIf{$f(x,y)$ analytic at $x_0$}
{ 
    Very long description here. very long description here. very long 
    description here. very long description here. Let\;

    \begin{align*}
    y &= y_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{ x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}  \, F_n(x,y)  \bigg\vert_{\substack{x=x_0\\y=y_0}}
    \end{align*}

     more very long description here. very long description here. 
     very long description here. very long description here.\;

     How to add paragraph spacing above this line?
}
{
   \eIf{ $f(x,y)$ not linear in $y(x)$}
    {
        \textbf{return}  \texttt{-{}-}     Not supported\;
    }
    {
    And so on
    }
}
   
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex in TL 2023.

I tried replacing `\;` by `\\` but this had no effect. I also tried adding `\raggedright` but this had no effect.

I looked and tried many other things from somewhat related question but not able to figure how to correct this.

I could force the vertical spacing between paragraphs by using `\vspace` like this new MWE below. So this fixes the paragraph spacing, but the initial shift on long lines still there

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\Input{$y'=f(x,y)$} 
Assume expansion around $x_0$ with initial conditions $y(x_0)=y_0$

\eIf{$f(x,y)$ analytic at $x_0$}
{ 
    Very long description here. very long description here. very long 
    description here. very long description here. Let\;
    %
    \begin{align*}
    y &= y_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{ x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}  \, F_n(x,y)  \bigg\vert_{\substack{x=x_0\\y=y_0}}
    \end{align*}
     %
     more very long description here. very long description here. 
     very long description here. very long description here.\;
     
     \vspace{6pt}
     How to add paragraph spacing above this line?
}
{
   \eIf{ $f(x,y)$ not linear in $y(x)$}
    {
        \textbf{return}  \texttt{-{}-}     Not supported\;
    }
    {
    And so on
    }
}
   
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The question is: How to make long lines that wrap all start left aligned with no shift. And if using `\vspace` to force space between paragraphs is the correct solution?

Comment: No need to load [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithms are set in the same way that regular paragraphs are. So, if you want to have some form of gap between *statements*, you'll have to force it somehow. So, use some form of `\vspace` for this. Below I use `\medskip`.

The other horizontal misalignment you see in wide statements (paragraphs) that wrap is caused by the hanging indent. You can remove this by adding `\SetAlgoHangIndent{0pt}` to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoHangIndent{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
  \Input{$y' = f(x, y)$} 
  Assume expansion around $x_0$ with initial conditions $y(x_0) = y_0$

  \eIf{$f(x, y)$ analytic at $x_0$}{%
    Very long description here. very long description here. very long 
    description here. very long description here. Let
    \[
      y = y_0 + 
        \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!} 
        \,
        F_n(x,y) \biggr\rvert_{\substack{x = x_0 \\ y = y_0}}
    \]
    more very long description here. very long description here. 
    very long description here. very long description here.\;
    
    \medskip

    How to add paragraph spacing above this line?\;
  }{
    \eIf{$f(x, y)$ not linear in $y(x)$}{%
      \textbf{return} \texttt{-{}-} Not supported\;
    }{%
      And so on
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```